# How to retrieve an object saved by numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I save an object of my class by numpy.save() and I can load it by numpy.load() but the value that I retrieve is: [<classes.SampleClass object at 0x7fb8ebd7a1f0>].

```
class SampleClass:
   
    def __init__(self, y):
        self.y = y


y=np.array([1,2,3])
x=SampleClass(y)
np.save("x",x, allow_pickle=True)

xx=np.load("x.npy")
```

This code is an example and `xx` value is [<classes.SampleClass object at 0x7fb8ebd7a1f0>]. How can I access to the values of `y` (`xx.y`)?

Comment: Please give a minimal example, also compare what you do to the examples given in the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html), please.

Comment: The *class* cannot be saved in a numpy file, only the array; in this case you are storing the class.  Perhaps you can use the `pickle` module to store (serialise) the class, or only pass the array into the save call.

Comment: @S3DEV I already saved it and I need to retrieve it now, Isn't it possible?

Comment: With `pickle`, yes. With `np.save`, not to my knowledge.  The docs say ‘save an array …’.

Comment: `xx.item()` or `xx[()]` `xx` is a 0d array, shape `()` with one element.

Comment: @S3DEV When I save the class I set "allow_pickle=True", I edited my question.

Comment: Use `from pickle import load, dump` instead of numpy's load and save, if you aim to store an arbitrary class instance. Numpy's load and save is only for the numpy arrays themselves.

Comment: @Dr.V, `np.save` wraps the object in an array and saves that.  It uses `pickle` to encode the object.  So `save` is practically the same.  `pickle` is a bit more direct, but no information is lost this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'allow_pickle' is required for the `load`, not the `save`.

```
In [2]: class SampleClass:
   ...: 
   ...:     def __init__(self, y):
   ...:         self.y = y
   ...: 
   ...: 
   ...: y=np.array([1,2,3])
   ...: x=SampleClass(y)
   ...: np.save("x",x)
   ...: xx=np.load("x.npy", allow_pickle=True)

In [2]: 

In [3]: xx
Out[3]: array(<__main__.SampleClass object at 0x000002583B8BCDC0>, dtype=object)
```

`xx` is a 0d object dtype array.  It has one element, which can be extracted with

```
In [4]: xx.item()
Out[4]: <__main__.SampleClass at 0x2583b8bcdc0>
```

or:

```
In [5]: xx[()]
Out[5]: <__main__.SampleClass at 0x2583b8bcdc0>
```

The `()` index matches the 0d shape of the array.